# База данных, интегрированная в программу для Linux

Tags: c++, linux, база-данных

Мне необходимо создать программу для ОС Linux, в которой нужна база данных. Прочитав многие источники, я не смог найти вариантов, где база данных находится в самой программе. Везде говорится лишь об обращении к базе, находящейся отдельно от программы, при помощи команд. Сам работаю в *Qt Creator* на *С++*. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно создать базу данных в самой программе.

Comment: Что значит в "самой программе", данные все таки желательно отдельно держать. А так SQLite как раз для интеграции предназначен

Comment: Как вариант ещё можно [*BerkeleyDB*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB) рассмотреть.

Answer (score 8):

> Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно создать базу данных в самой программе

Зависит от срока жизни этой самой базы.

Если он ограничен временем работы программы - храните всё в памяти, выбрав подходящие структуры данных, проблем с этим никаких (ну, кроме ограничений по доступной памяти).

Если же нужно сохранять данные между запусками программы, то без внешнего хранилища не обойтись. Теоретически вы можете модифицировать сам исполняемый файл, но этот вариант даже обсуждать не хочется.

Посмотрите для начала в сторону [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). Qt умеет работать с ней "из коробки", да и библиотеки, что сишные, что плюсовые, имеются. Сама по себе база представляет один файл, который не требует наличия на клиентской машине какого-то дополнительного ПО.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по формулировке вопроса, если я ошибаюсь то поправьте меня, вы только начали изучать программирование, и это одно из ваших заданий.

Термин "База данных" - это хранилище информации с интерфейсом для програмного управления содержанием. Она тоже, как не странно, сама является "программой".

"Создать программу" - это наверно подразумевается написание пользовательского приложения, работающего с базой данных.

"создать базу данных в самой программе" - это наверно использовать встроенную базу данных, подключенную как модуль. Для этих целей чаще всего используют SQLite.

Чтобы понять что происходит, и как  это делается, вероятно Вам нужна пошаговая инструкция:

- запускаем Qt Creator
- если у Вас Qt Creator на русском, то я рекомендовал бы переключиться на английский. Для этого выбираем в меню "Инструменты" -> "Параметры..."
- в окне "Параметры" слева выбираем "Среда" -> открываем вкладку "Основные" -> выбираем в выпадающем списке "English" -> нажимаем кнопку "OK" -> перезапускаем Qt Creator
- в меню Qt Creator'а выбираем "File" -> "New File or Project..." (Ctrl+N)
- в разделе "Projects" выбираем "Applications" -> во второй колонке выбираем "Qt Widgets Application"
- нажимаем кнопку "Choose"
- в поле "Name" вводим: DatabaseLoginForm и нажимаем "Next" (2 раза)
- в поле "Base Class" выбираем "QDialog" -> нажимаем "Next" -> нажимаем "Finish"
- скачиваем исходный код проекта (кнопка "Download ZIP" справа-внизу): https://github.com/8Observer8/DatabaseLoginForm
- заменяем файлы текущего проекта на файлы из скаченного
- нажимаем Ctrl+R, чтобы запустить программу

оригинал тут: http://www.prog.org.ru/topic_26665_0.html